# Redirect the url to login page WHMCS development

Tags: php, whmcs

From the WHMCS development [tutorial](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/), I created a page success.

but in the example code:

```
if ($ca->isLoggedIn()) {

    $clientName = Capsule::table('tblclients')
        ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->pluck('firstname');
    // 'pluck' was renamed within WHMCS 7.0.  Replace it with 'value' instead.
    // ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->value('firstname');
    $ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);

} else {

    // User is not logged in
    $ca->assign('clientname', 'Random User');

}
```

if the `isLoggedIn` is `false`, I want to redirect the url to login page, how to realize this?

Comment: `header()`...? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for creating pages in WHMCS https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/

The short answer is `$ca->requireLogin();` if you put this in the code people will not be able to visit the page without logging in, and will be redirected to the login page if they are not logged in.